# flicking in switching css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var loadCSS = function(id,page) {
    $('#block').css('opacity',1);

     $("link[type='text/css']").remove();

     var cssLink = $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/'+id+'-item-' + page+ '.css">');
     $("head").append(cssLink); 

 };
```

I try to switch css using above code, the problem is there will be a flick. I tried to set my #block to opacity and try to use the transition trick, but it doesn't work. How to resolve the flickering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the opacity:
In your function make it: `$('#block').addClass('trans-level');`
In your old old css file or current html page:

```
.trans-level{opacity:0;}
```

Then in your new css file:

```
.trans-level{ opacity: 1;}
```